# find and delete from more-dimensional numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two numpy-arrays:

```
p_a_colors=np.array([[0,0,0],
                     [0,2,0],
                     [119,103,82],
                     [122,122,122],
                     [122,122,122],
                     [3,2,4]])

p_rem = np.array([[119,103,82],
                     [122,122,122]])
```

I want to delete all the columns from p_a_colors that are in p_rem, so I get:

```
p_r_colors=np.array([[0,0,0],
                    [0,2,0],
                    [3,2,4]])
```

I think, something should work like

```
p_r_colors= np.delete(p_a_colors, np.where(np.all(p_a_colors==p_rem, axis=0)),0)
```

but I just don't get the axis or [:] right.

I know, that

```
p_r_colors=copy.deepcopy(p_a_colors)
for i in range(len(p_rem)):
    p_r_colors= np.delete(p_r_colors, np.where(np.all(p_r_colors==p_rem[i], axis=-1)),0)
```

would work, but I am trying to avoid (python)loops, because I also want the performance right.

Comment: Hold on. What is this code supposed to do?

Comment: It should give me a new numpy.array p_r_colors, which is p_a_colors-p_rem, same shape as the 2 other arrays

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

```
dtype = np.dtype((np.void, (p_a_colors.shape[1] * 
                            p_a_colors.dtype.itemsize)))
mask = np.in1d(p_a_colors.view(dtype), p_rem.view(dtype))
p_r_colors = p_a_colors[~mask]

>>> p_r_colors
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 2, 0],
       [3, 2, 4]])
```

You need to do the void dtype thing so that numpy compares rows as a whole. After that using the built-in set routines seems like the obvious way to go.

Answer (score 1):

It's ugly, but

```
tmp = reduce(lambda x, y: x |  np.all(p_a_colors == y, axis=-1), p_rem, np.zeros(p_a_colors.shape[:1], dtype=np.bool))

indices = np.where(tmp)[0]

np.delete(p_a_colors, indices, axis=0)
```

(edit: corrected)

```
>>> tmp = reduce(lambda x, y: x |  np.all(p_a_colors == y, axis=-1), p_rem, np.zeros(p_a_colors.shape[:1], dtype=np.bool))
>>> 
>>> indices = np.where(tmp)[0]
>>> 
>>> np.delete(p_a_colors, indices, axis=0)
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 2, 0],
       [3, 2, 4]])
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the indices wrong. The expression `p_a_colors==p_rem` evaluates to an empty array, because the two arrays are never equal (they have different shapes!). If you want to use `np.delete`, you need a more correct list of indices.

On the other hand, this can be more easily done with indices:

```
>>> idx = np.array([p_a_colors[i] not in p_rem for i in
                    range(p_a_colors.shape[0])], dtype='bool')
>>> p_a_colors[idx]
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 2, 0],
       [3, 2, 4]])
```

Or, inspired by the suggestion of @Jaime, you can also create the indices with `np.in1d`, here in one line:

```
>>> idx = ~np.all(np.in1d(p_a_colors, p_rem).reshape(p_a_colors.shape), 
                  axis=1)
>>> p_a_colors[idx]
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 2, 0],
       [3, 2, 4]])
```

If you must use `np.delete`, just convert the list of indices from `bool` to a sequence:

```
>>> idx = np.array([p_a_colors[i] in p_rem for i in 
                          range(p_a_colors.shape[0])])
>>> idx = np.arange(p_a_colors.shape[0])[idx]
>>> np.delete(p_a_colors, idx, axis=0)
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 2, 0],
       [3, 2, 4]])
```

Comment: something went wrong. I tried it with large arrays and it deleted to much.

Comment: Which version did you try? Did the arrays have more than 2 dimensions?

Comment: I did the second version. No everything should have been the same, but with much more values. I already implemted Jaime's version. That seems to work fine.

Comment: The resaon `~np.all(np.in1d(p_a_colors, p_rem).reshape(p_a_colors.shape),axis=1)` gives incorrect results is that it just says (before negation) that all members of a given row are in the other array, but not necessarily in the same row.