# Python version of ismember with 'rows' and index

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

The similar question has been asked, but none of the answers quite do what I need - some allow multidimensional searches (aka 'rows' option in matlab) but dont return the index.  Some return the index but dont allow rows.  My arrays are very large (1M x 2) and I have bee successful in making a loop that works, but obviously that is very slow.  In matlab, the built-in ismember function takes about 10 seconds.

Here is what I am looking for:

```
a=np.array([[4, 6],[2, 6],[5, 2]])

b=np.array([[1, 7],[1, 8],[2, 6],[2, 1],[2, 4],[4, 6],[4, 7],[5, 9],[5, 2],[5, 1]])
```

The exact matlab function that does the trick is:

```
[~,index] = ismember(a,b,'rows')
```

where

```
index = [6, 3, 9]
```

Comment: What is the dtype of your arrays? Is both `a` and `b` of length ~1M? Does the order of values in `index` matter to you?

Comment: They are both dtype('int64').  b is length ~1M, and a is length ~750k.  Every entry in a will be in b, but not the reverse.  Ideally the index output would be the same length as b whose value shows the index within a.

Comment: sorry... I meant the output should be the same length as a. It wouldn't make sense the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np

def asvoid(arr):
    """
    View the array as dtype np.void (bytes)
    This views the last axis of ND-arrays as bytes so you can perform comparisons on
    the entire row.
    http://stackoverflow.com/a/16840350/190597 (Jaime, 2013-05)
    Warning: When using asvoid for comparison, note that float zeros may compare UNEQUALLY
    >>> asvoid([-0.]) == asvoid([0.])
    array([False], dtype=bool)
    """
    arr = np.ascontiguousarray(arr)
    return arr.view(np.dtype((np.void, arr.dtype.itemsize * arr.shape[-1])))


def in1d_index(a, b):
    voida, voidb = map(asvoid, (a, b))
    return np.where(np.in1d(voidb, voida))[0]    

a = np.array([[4, 6],[2, 6],[5, 2]])
b = np.array([[1, 7],[1, 8],[2, 6],[2, 1],[2, 4],[4, 6],[4, 7],[5, 9],[5, 2],[5, 1]])

print(in1d_index(a, b))
```

prints

```
[2 5 8]
```

This would be equivalent to Matlab's [3, 6, 9], since Python uses 0-based indexing.

Some caveats:

1. The indices are returned in increasing order. They do not correspond
   to the location of the items of `a` in `b`.
2. asvoid will work for integer dtypes, but be careful if using asvoid
   on float dtypes, since `asvoid([-0.]) == asvoid([0.])` returns
   `array([False])`.
3. asvoid works best on contiguous arrays. If the arrays are not contiguous, the data will be copied to a contiguous array, which will slow down the performance.

---

Despite the caveats, one might choose to use `in1d_index` anyway for the sake of speed:

```
def ismember_rows(a, b):
    # http://stackoverflow.com/a/22705773/190597 (ashg)
    return np.nonzero(np.all(b == a[:,np.newaxis], axis=2))[1]

In [41]: a2 = np.tile(a,(2000,1))
In [42]: b2 = np.tile(b,(2000,1))

In [46]: %timeit in1d_index(a2, b2)
100 loops, best of 3: 8.49 ms per loop

In [47]: %timeit ismember_rows(a2, b2)
1 loops, best of 3: 5.55 s per loop
```

So `in1d_index`  is ~650x faster (for arrays of length in the low thousands), but again note the comparison is not exactly apples-to-apples since `in1d_index` returns the indices in increasing order, while `ismember_rows` returns the indices in the order rows of `a` show up in `b`.

Comment: Thanks for these suggestions.  I will not have contiguous arrays, however its possible that I could first sort a (assuming I can also get the index of the sorting, this may be possible with argsort?) then I could do what you are suggesting.

Comment: You might want to see how `in1d_index` performs without doing anything special first. The `arr = np.ascontiguousarray(arr)` will make the inputs contiguous if they are not already.

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np 
def ismember_rows(a, b):
    '''Equivalent of 'ismember' from Matlab
    a.shape = (nRows_a, nCol)
    b.shape = (nRows_b, nCol)
    return the idx where b[idx] == a
    '''
    return np.nonzero(np.all(b == a[:,np.newaxis], axis=2))[1]

a = np.array([[4, 6],[2, 6],[5, 2]])
b = np.array([[1, 7],[1, 8],[2, 6],[2, 1],[2, 4],[4, 6],[4, 7],[5, 9],[5, 2],[5, 1]])
idx = ismember_rows(a, b)
print idx
print np.all(b[idx] == a)
```

print

```
array([5, 2, 8])
True
```

e...I used broadcasting

--------------------------[update]------------------------------

```
def ismember(a, b):
    return np.flatnonzero(np.in1d(b[:,0], a[:,0]) & np.in1d(b[:,1], a[:,1]))

a = np.array([[4, 6],[2, 6],[5, 2]])
b = np.array([[1, 7],[1, 8],[2, 6],[2, 1],[2, 4],[4, 6],[4, 7],[5, 9],[5, 2],[5, 1]])
a2 = np.tile(a,(2000,1))
b2 = np.tile(b,(2000,1))

%timeit timeit in1d_index(a2, b2)
# 100 loops, best of 3: 8.74 ms per loop
%timeit ismember(a2, b2)
# 100 loops, best of 3: 8.5 ms per loop

np.all(in1d_index(a2, b2) == ismember(a2, b2))
# True
```

as what unutbu said, the indices are returned in increasing order

Comment: I tried running this, and it killed my kernel, unfortunately.  I have very big arrays...

Comment: Warning : unfortunately, this solution is not working when values appears several times in the same column since it does not verify that a couple of values of 'a' exists in 'b' but only if values of each column of 'a' exist in each columns of 'b'.

Comment: another Warning: this does not appear to work if entries in a are not found in b for example `a = np.array([[4, 6],[6, 6],[5, 2]])`. This doesn't seem to be a good answer for a replacement of the matlab func

Answer (score 0):

The function first turns multiple columns of elements into a single column array, then numpy.in1d can be used to find out the desire answer, please try the following code:

```
import numpy as np

def ismemberRow(A,B):
    '''
    This function is find which rows found in A can be also found in B,
    The function first turns multiple columns of elements into a single column array, then numpy.in1d can be used

    Input: m x n numpy array (A), and p x q array (B)
    Output unique numpy array with length m, storing either True or False, True for rows can be found in both A and B
    '''

    sa = np.chararray((A.shape[0],1))
    sa[:] = '-'
    sb = np.chararray((B.shape[0],1))
    sb[:] = '-'

    ba = (A).astype(np.str)
    sa2 = np.expand_dims(ba[:,0],axis=1) + sa + np.expand_dims(ba[:,1],axis=1)
    na = A.shape[1] - 2    

    for i in range(0,na):
         sa2 = sa2 + sa + np.expand_dims(ba[:,i+2],axis=1)

    bb = (B).astype(np.str)
    sb2 = np.expand_dims(bb[:,0],axis=1) + sb + np.expand_dims(bb[:,1],axis=1)
    nb = B.shape[1] - 2    

    for i in range(0,nb):
         sb2 = sb2 + sb + np.expand_dims(bb[:,i+2],axis=1)

    return np.in1d(sa2,sb2)

A = np.array([[1, 3, 4],[2, 4, 3],[7, 4, 3],[1, 1, 1],[1, 3, 4],[5, 3, 4],[1, 1, 1],[2, 4, 3]])

B = np.array([[1, 3, 4],[1, 1, 1]])

d = ismemberRow(A,B)

print A[np.where(d)[0],:]

#results:
#[[1 3 4]
# [1 1 1]
# [1 3 4]
# [1 1 1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function based on [libigl's `igl::ismember_rows`](https://github.com/libigl/libigl/blob/main/include/igl/ismember_rows.cpp) which closely mimics the behavior of Matlab's `ismember(A,B,'rows')`:

```py
def ismember_rows(A,B, return_index=False):
    """
    Return whether each row in A occurs as a row in B
    
    Parameters
    ----------
    A : #A by dim array
    B : #B by dim array
    return_index : {True,False}, optional.
    
    Returns
    -------
    IA : #A 1D array, IA[i] == True if and only if
        there exists j = LOCB[i] such that B[j,:] == A[i,:]
    LOCB : #A 1D array of indices. LOCB[j] == -1 if IA[i] == False, 
        only returned if return_index=True
    """
    IA = np.full(A.shape[0],False)
    LOCB = np.full(A.shape[0],-1)
    if len(A) == 0: return (IA,LOCB) if return_index else IA
    if len(B) == 0: return (IA,LOCB) if return_index else IA
    # Get rid of any duplicates
    uA,uIuA = np.unique(A, axis=0, return_inverse=True)
    uB,uIB = np.unique(B, axis=0, return_index=True)
    # Sort both
    sIA = np.lexsort(uA.T[::-1])
    sA = uA[sIA,:]
    sIB = np.lexsort(uB.T[::-1])
    sB = uB[sIB,:]
    #
    uF = np.full(sA.shape[0],False)
    uLOCB = np.full(sA.shape[0],-1)
    def row_greater_than(a,b):
        for c in range(sA.shape[1]):
            if(sA[a,c] > sB[b,c]): return True
            if(sA[a,c] < sB[b,c]): return False
        return False
    # loop over sA
    bi = 0
    past = False
    for a in range(sA.shape[0]):
        while not past and row_greater_than(a,bi):
            bi+=1
            past = bi>=sB.shape[0]
        if not past and np.all(sA[a,:]==sB[bi,:]):
            uF[sIA[a]] = True
            uLOCB[sIA[a]] = uIB[sIB[bi]]
    for a in range(A.shape[0]):
        IA[a] = uF[uIuA[a]]
        LOCB[a] = uLOCB[uIuA[a]]
    return (IA,LOCB) if return_index else IA
```

For example,

```py
a=np.array([[4, 6],[6,6],[2, 6],[5, 2]])
b=np.array([[1, 7],[1, 8],[2, 6],[2, 1],[2, 4],[4, 6],[4, 7],[5, 9],[5, 2],[5, 1]])
(flag,index) = ismember_rows(a,b,return_index=True)
```

produces

```
>>> flag
array([ True, False,  True,  True])
>>> index
array([ 5, -1,  2,  8])
```

**Update**: Here's a faster version that makes better use of [`numpy.unique`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) based on [`array_correspondence` in gpytoolbox](https://gpytoolbox.org/0.0.3/array_correspondence/).

```py
def ismember_rows(A,B,return_index=False):
    """
    Return whether each row in A occurs as a row in B
    
    Parameters
    ----------
    A : #A by dim array
    B : #B by dim array
    return_index : {True,False}, optional.
    
    Returns
    -------
    IA : #A 1D array, IA[i] == True if and only if
        there exists j = LOCB[i] such that B[j,:] == A[i,:]
    LOCB : #A 1D array of indices. LOCB[j] == -1 if IA[i] == False, 
        only returned if return_index=True
    """
    if len(A) == 0 or len(B) == 0:
        IA = np.full(A.shape[0],False)
        LOCB = np.full(A.shape[0],-1)
        return (IA,LOCB) if return_index else IA
    uB,mapB = np.unique(B,axis=0, return_index=True)
    uU,idx,inv = np.unique(np.vstack((uB,A)),axis=0,return_index=True, return_inverse=True)
    imap = idx[inv[uB.shape[0]:]]
    imap[imap>=uB.shape[0]] = -1
    LOCB = np.where(imap<0, -1, mapB[imap])
    IA = LOCB>=0
    return (IA,LOCB) if return_index else IA
```

Seems to be a bit faster on my laptop.

Comment: It would be nice if you could time your two approaches and show the results. Since you're reviving a very old question, it would be amazing if you could also time these against the _other_ methods shown by the existing answers. If you'd like a skeleton code, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75114333/843953): Replace the `sliding_median_lc` and `sliding_median_np` function definitions, and `arg_gen` should take the size of the array and return a list or a tuple containing an argument to your function call for an array of that size