# What is efficient way to write sliding median in Numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to implement a sliding median over an array like below:

```
def sliding_median(arr, window):
    ret = [np.median(arr[i:i+window]) for i in range(len(arr) - window+1)]
    return np.array(ret)
```

but as you see here, I used a python list comprehension that won't be as fast as using a numpy function. Is there a way I can get the sliding median using any numpy functions?

Comment: I don't think any _dead_ numpy experts are going to be able to answer your question anytime soon :)

Comment: i edited, i dkn why it is some typing correction here what makes that.

Answer (score 4):

Use a [`numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html) (available in numpy v1.20.0+)

```
swindow = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(data, (length,))
```

This gives you a `Mxlength` array, where each row is a single window. Then, you can simply use `np.median` along the first axis to get a rowwise median. Implementing this in your function:

```
def sliding_median(arr, window):
    return np.median(np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(arr, (window,)), axis=1)
```

Comparing the runtimes of this method against your list-comprehension approach gives the following results:

- `sliding_median_lc`: Your list-comprehension approach
- `sliding_median_np`: The sliding-window-view numpy approach

[image]

Predictably, the numpy function is orders of magnitude faster for the larger inputs. For arrays that are comparable to the window size, the list-comprehension is faster because it avoids the overheads involved in building the sliding window view.

If you're interested, here's the code I used to make this plot:

```
import timeit
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def time_funcs(funcs, sizes, arg_gen, N=20):
    times = np.zeros((len(sizes), len(funcs)))
    gdict = globals().copy()
    for i, s in enumerate(sizes):
        args = arg_gen(s)
        print(args)
        for j, f in enumerate(funcs):
            gdict.update(locals())
            try:
                times[i, j] = timeit.timeit("f(*args)", globals=gdict, number=N) / N
                print(f"{i}/{len(sizes)}, {j}/{len(funcs)}, {times[i, j]}")
            except ValueError:
                print("ERROR in {f}({*args})")
                
            
    return times

def plot_times(times, funcs):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    for j, f in enumerate(funcs):
        ax.plot(sizes, times[:, j], label=f.__name__)
    
    
    ax.set_xlabel("Array size")
    ax.set_ylabel("Time per function call (s)")
    ax.set_xscale("log")
    ax.set_yscale("log")
    ax.legend()
    ax.grid()
    fig.tight_layout()
    return fig, ax

#%%
def arg_gen(n):
    return [np.random.randint(-100, 100, (n,)), 5]
    
#%%
def sliding_median_lc(arr, window):
    return np.array([np.median(arr[i:i+window]) for i in range(len(arr) - window+1)])
    

def sliding_median_np(arr, window):    
    return np.median(np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(arr, (window,)), axis=1)

#%% 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    #%% Set up sim
    sizes = [5, 10, 50, 100, 500, 1000, 5000, 10_000, 50_000, 100_000]
    funcs = [sliding_median_lc, sliding_median_np]
    
    
    #%% Run timing
    time_fcalls = np.zeros((len(sizes), len(funcs))) * np.nan
    time_fcalls = time_funcs(funcs, sizes, arg_gen)
    
    fig, ax = plot_times(time_fcalls, funcs)
    ax.set_xlabel(f"Input size")

    plt.show()
```

Comment: Ok, you were 20 seconds sooner. I delete my answer, and upvote this one. (But `sliding_window_view` makes 1/3 of my reputation points, so please, don't take all of them from me :D)

Comment: @chrslg haha, no worries. I've recently restarted playing with numpy after using it extensively when I was in grad school. `sliding_window_view` would have made my life so much easier back then :)