# Comparing two matrices in Python, and filling the missed rows

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, compare

I have two matrices of features, that have different number of rows.
Suppose matrix A has more rows than matrix B. The columns of matrices includes ID1, ID2, Time_slice, feature value. Since for some Time_slice there is no feature value in B, the number of rows in B is less than A. I require to find which rows are missed in B. Then add rows to B with related ID1, ID2 values, and zero for the feature.

```
            ID1  ID2 Time_slice Feature
A= array([[ 100,  1.,   0.,     1.5],
          [ 100,  1.,   1.,     3.7],
          [ 100,  2.,   0.,     1.2],
         [ 100,   2.,   1.,     1.8],
         [ 100,   2.,   2.,     2.9],
         [ 101,   3.,   0.,     1.5],
          [ 101,  3.,   1.,     3.7],
          [ 101,  4.,   0.,     1.2],
         [ 101,   4.,   1.,     1.8],
         [ 101,   4.,   2.,     2.9]])

B= array([[ 100,  1.,   0.,     1.25],
          [ 100,  1.,   1.,     3.37],
          [ 100,  2.,   0.,     1.42],
         [ 100,   2.,   1.,     1.68]])

Output should be as follow:

         [[ 100,  1.,   0.,     1.25],
          [ 100,  1.,   1.,     3.37],
          [ 100,  2.,   0.,     1.42],
         [ 100,   2.,   1.,     1.68],
         [ 100,   2.,   2.,     0  ],
         [ 101,   3.,   0.,     0],
          [ 101,  3.,   1.,     0],
          [ 101,  4.,   0.,     0],
         [ 101,   4.,   1.,     0],
         [ 101,   4.,   2.,     0]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[ 100,  1.,   0.,     1.5],
          [ 100,  1.,   1.,     3.7],
          [ 100,  2.,   0.,     1.2],
          [ 100,  2.,   1.,     1.8],
          [ 100,  2.,   2.,     2.9],
          [ 101,  3.,   0.,     1.5],
          [ 101,  3.,   1.,     3.7],
          [ 101,  4.,   0.,     1.2],
          [ 101,  4.,   1.,     1.8],
          [ 101,  4.,   2.,     2.9]])

B = np.array([[ 100,  1.,   0.,     1.25],
          [ 100,  1.,   1.,     3.37],
          [ 100,  2.,   0.,     1.42],
          [ 100,  2.,   1.,     1.68]])

listB = B.tolist()

for rowA in A:
    if rowA.tolist not in listB:
        B = np.append(B, [[rowA[0], rowA[1], rowA[2], 0]], axis=0)

print B
```

Comment: It would be better to append, or insert the new rows into a list (`listB` or a new copy), and rebuild the array at the end.  Repeated use of `np.append` is slow.

Comment: I did some changes in your code to compare the first three columns, and I tried the same method as @hpaulj said to optimize the speed. Thanks.

Comment: @hpaulj, yes repeated use of np.append is slow. Work on the list and finalize it to an array at the end is better for perf. I wasn't thinking about perf when coming out with a quick answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It appears (from the desired output) that a row in A is thought to match a row
in B if the first three columns are equal. Your problem would be in large part solved if we could identify which rows of `A` match rows of `B`.

If identifying matches simply depended on values from a *single* column, then we could use [`np.in1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html). For example, if `[0, 1, 2, 5 ,0]` were values in `A` and `[0, 2]` were values in `B`, then

```
In [39]: np.in1d([0, 1, 2, 5, 0], [0, 2])
Out[39]: array([ True, False,  True, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

shows which rows of `A` match rows of `B`.

There is (currently) no higher-dimensional generalization of this function in NumPy.

There is a trick, however, which can be used to *view* multiple columns of a 2D array *as a single column* of byte values -- thus turning a 2D array into a 1D array. We can then apply `np.in1d` to this 1D array. The trick, which I [learned from Jaime](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16840350/190597), is here encapsulated in the function, `asvoid`:

```
import numpy as np

def asvoid(arr):
    """
    View the array as dtype np.void (bytes).

    This views the last axis of ND-arrays as np.void (bytes) so
    comparisons can be performed on the entire row.
    https://stackoverflow.com/a/16840350/190597 (Jaime, 2013-05)

    Some caveats:
        - `asvoid` will work for integer dtypes, but be careful if using asvoid on float
        dtypes, since float zeros may compare UNEQUALLY:
        >>> asvoid([-0.]) == asvoid([0.])
        array([False], dtype=bool)

        - `asvoid` works best on contiguous arrays. If the input is not contiguous,
        `asvoid` will copy the array to make it contiguous, which will slow down the
        performance.

    """
    arr = np.ascontiguousarray(arr)
    return arr.view(np.dtype((np.void, arr.dtype.itemsize * arr.shape[-1])))

A = np.array([[ 100,  1.,   0.,     1.5],
              [ 100,  1.,   1.,     3.7],
              [ 100,  2.,   0.,     1.2],
              [ 100,   2.,   1.,     1.8],
              [ 100,   2.,   2.,     2.9],
              [ 101,   3.,   0.,     1.5],
              [ 101,  3.,   1.,     3.7],
              [ 101,  4.,   0.,     1.2],
              [ 101,   4.,   1.,     1.8],
              [ 101,   4.,   2.,     2.9]])

B = np.array([[ 100,  1.,   0.,     1.25],
              [ 100,  1.,   1.,     3.37],
              [ 100,  2.,   0.,     1.42],
              [ 100,   2.,   1.,     1.68]])

mask = np.in1d(asvoid(A[:, :3]), asvoid(B[:, :3]))
result = A[~mask]
result[:, -1] = 0
result = np.row_stack([B, result])
print(result)
```

yields

```
[[ 100.      1.      0.      1.25]
 [ 100.      1.      1.      3.37]
 [ 100.      2.      0.      1.42]
 [ 100.      2.      1.      1.68]
 [ 100.      2.      2.      0.  ]
 [ 101.      3.      0.      0.  ]
 [ 101.      3.      1.      0.  ]
 [ 101.      4.      0.      0.  ]
 [ 101.      4.      1.      0.  ]
 [ 101.      4.      2.      0.  ]]
```